# Stokes type-formula

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, stokes-theorem

Let $X$ be a complex manifold.
Is the following identity true?

$$\int_X\overline {\partial} \alpha=\int_{\partial X} \alpha$$
where $\alpha $ is a differential form on $X$, and $\partial X $ is the boundary of $X$.

The same question if we replace $\overline {\partial} \alpha $ by $\partial \alpha $?

Comment: What happened to the correct version, with $d$? Are you assuming $\alpha$ is a $(p,q)$-form for particular $p$ and $q$?

Comment: Let $\alpha'=\partial \alpha$. When $\alpha'=\partial X, \alpha=X$

Answer (score 6):

Let $X$ be the unit disk in the complex plane, $\alpha=-z\,d\bar{z}$, so $\bar\partial\alpha=0$, but $\int_{\partial X}\alpha=2\pi i$. Conjugate this example to get an example for $\partial$.